# Extend a non-static class with a protected constructor

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extend Selenium's By class [found here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/73adfc952265cc9496001e1a71e5403a98e20dcd/dotnet/src/webdriver/By.cs).

```
public static class SeleniumExtensions
{
  public static By Text(this By by, string textToFind)
  {
    return By.XPath("");
  }
}
```

But I can't find my extension on the By class when I do the above.

Comment: Do you have a `using` statement containing the namespace that `SeleniumExtensions` is defined in?

Comment: @canton7 I have, yes

Comment: How are you trying to call it?

Comment: driver.IsVisible(By.Text("Sales")); gives me 'By does not contain a definition for Text'

Comment: Right. Extension methods work on *instances* of the type. So you could do `By by = ...; by.Text(...)`. But you can't add static methods to the `By` class

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it on an *instance* of the `By` class, not on the `By` *class* itself.
For example:

```
By by = ...;
by.Text("Sales");
```

Comment: I can't create an instance because the constructor is marked as protected. So I'm guessing what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: Are not subclasses of By? If not, then, yes, it is not possible, but I can't believe that there aren't. The extension method will apply to any subclasses, as they are By themselves.

Comment: @marceli You can create an instance e.g. by calling `By.XPath(...)`. But that probably isn't what you *want* here